Rayleigh quotient achieves its maximum on a nonzero subspace
Let $A$ be a linear operator on $V$, an Euclidean space equipped with the standard inner product. For $x\in V$ with $x\neq0$ we define the Rayleigh quotient of $A$ at $x$ as
$$R_{A}(x)=\langle x,Ax \rangle /\langle x,x \rangle$$
I want to prove the following: let $U$ be a nonzero subspace of $V$. Then $R_{A}$ takes its maximum on $U\diagdown\{0\}$.
I approach it in the following way: To show that $R_A(x)$ takes its maximum on $U - \{0\}$ we will show that for any $\lambda x$ where $\lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$, the value of $R_A$ remains unchanged, constant function. If we can show that it's continuous, we are done. Note the following: \begin{align*}
    R_{A}(\lambda x)&=\frac{\left\langle \lambda x,A\lambda x\right\rangle }{\left\langle \lambda x,\lambda x\right\rangle} \\ &= \frac{\lambda \left\langle  x,\lambda A x\right\rangle }{ \lambda^2\left\langle x, x\right\rangle} \\ &= \frac{\lambda^2 \left\langle  x, A x\right\rangle }{ \lambda^2\left\langle x, x\right\rangle} \\ &=  R_{A}( x)\end{align*} But this shows that when $U$ is a one dimensional subspace, a line, Rayleigh quotient is a constant function. In the general case (say for simiplicity $x = \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y$), we have: $$R_{A}(\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y) = \frac{\lambda_1^2  \left\langle x, Ax\right\rangle + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \left\langle x, Ay\right\rangle + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \left\langle Ax, y\right\rangle + \lambda_2^2  \left\langle y, Ay\right\rangle}{\lambda_1^2  \left\langle x, x\right\rangle +2 \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \left\langle x, y\right\rangle + \lambda_2^2  \left\langle y, y\right\rangle }$$ (1) I don't see how this results in a constant function. Next, (2) What might be a way to show that $R_A(x): V \to \mathbb{R}$ defines a continuous function?

I was missing a crucial piece of information. Recall that finite-dimensional Euclidean spaces always have an orthonormal basis. So, we can normalize our vectors in $U$ without any trouble because $R_A$ is scaling invariant. It gives us the compact unit sphere and it can be easily shown that $R_A$ is a polynomial (hence continuous). I will write a proper, detailed answer sometime soon, but that's the gist I think.
